# Why does Moq sometimes require explicit type declaration in Returns?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, delegates, moq

Why does this work `Returns((string food) => eat(food))` while this doesn't: `Returns(food => eat(food))` ?

Full working example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var animal = new Mock<IAnimal>();
        Func<string, string> eat = food => $"Nom nom nom {food}";

        // works
        animal.Setup(a => a.Eat(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(eat);

        // works
        animal.Setup(a => a.Eat(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((string food) => eat(food));

        //cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
        animal.Setup(a => a.Eat(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(food => eat(food));

        //cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
        animal.Setup(a => a.Eat(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(food => $"Nom nom nom {food}");
    }
}

public interface IAnimal
{
    string Eat(string food);
}
```

Comment: It isn't Moq that requires this, it's the C# compiler. It is likely that the huge number of overloads of the `.Returns` method (18 at my counting) that gives the compiler too many options. Also, in the future, when code doesn't work (as in, doesn't compile), please post the actual error message. In this case it is "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen To be fair the error is embedded in code comments, though I agree it should be more obvious.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I get that, but I only noticed this behaviour in the Moq Returns function, and I'm curious what trips the compiler in not finding the proper method to call. I expect there is a conflict with some of the other methods in Returns, but which?

Comment: I see that now, sorry about that, but nevertheless, the rest of my comment stands, this is not a Moq problem, this is solely a C# problem (though as I mentioned, it may be that the number of overloads create this problem). The type inference for generics doesn't solve all problems, something which advocates of functional programming has learned the hard way, the C# compiler handles a huge number of cases, but not all that it could. I can't tell you exactly which overload or combination of overloads that trips up the compiler here but I've seen the problem countless times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replying as an answer so I can paste some code...

It's not the number of overloads as Lasse V. Karlsen suggests. The behaviour is due to casting. See comments in code below:

```
//works because "eat" knows it's own input type
animal.Setup(a => a.Eat(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(eat);

// works because you are explicitly typing input param
animal.Setup(a => a.Eat(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((string food) => eat(food));
```

However, things get a bit trickier when you use a lambda expression, because the lambda expression doesn't actually have an input type

```
animal.Setup(a => a.Eat(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((string food) => eat(food));
// is equivalent to:
animal.Setup(a => a.Eat(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((string food) => {return eat(food); });
```

But `{return eat(food);}` doesn't know what type `food` is.

Thus, when you call

```
animal.Setup(a => a.Eat(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(food => eat(food));
animal.Setup(a => a.Eat(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(food => $"Nom nom nom {food}");
```

the compiler does not know what type food is.